# Weighted random sort

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting

I need to sort an array of objects randomly based on their weights. I have made the following function:

```
function weightedRandomSort($objects) {
    uasort($objects, function($a, $b) {
        $rand = rand(1, 9999) / 10000;
        $totalWeight = $a->weight + $b->weight;
        $probabilityA = $a->weight / $totalWeight;  
        if ($rand < $probabilityA) return 1; // a > b
        else return -1;
    });

    return $objects;
}
```

The function works but based on my tests, I feel that it does not work correctly. Does anyone notice if there is something wrong with the logic?

Comment: Did you not reverse 1 and -1 ? If $a weight is 1 and $b is 0, we should always have $a first, but in your case it's the opposite

Comment: Any particular reason to use 1 and 9999 as the range boundary?  Not that it will make much difference, but isn't 0 and 10000 more accurate?

Comment: Some sample data and the expected output will help.

Comment: It's a bit of a contraction to say "random" and then sort them according to `weight` at the same time. The problem is that this sorting routine is not deterministic. The answer of the callable function should always be the same. Why not sort the array first according to weight, and then introduce a bit of randomization. Knowing _why_ you want to do this could help a lot.

Comment: "I feel"...on what basis? Show the tests you used, and the results you expected, and the results you got. And explain the precise logic you're trying to implement. Ambiguity is not the programmer's friend.

Comment: I do this approach when I need weighted random values. https://3v4l.org/e0Yjh Then there is no need to sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to sort your elements such that the odds of each element being the first element are proportional to their weights. The odds of each being the second are proportional to their weights if they are not the first. And so on.

The problem with your current logic is that it is very heavily dependent on how the sort is implemented. For example if sort is internally a [quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), then the first pivot chosen goes through `O(n)` comparisons, while most elements go through `O(log(n))` comparisons. It is harder to win `n` comparisons in a row than `O(log(n))`, and therefore the odds of an element winning depend both on its weight, and whether it is chosen to be an early pivot.

What you want can be trivially implemented in time `O(n^2)` by having a function to sample randomly based on weight. Take a sample for the first, then remove it. Take a sample for the second then remove it. And so on. I assume that you want more efficient than this naive approach.

The trick is to use the [Exponential Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution). You can sample from it in PHP with [stats_rand_gen_exponential](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stats-rand-gen-exponential.php). Let me explain how it works.

Suppose you have a chunk of radioactive material. There are a large number of atoms, each of which could decay at any moment, but which are individually unlikely to. When one does decay, you'll hear a [Geiger counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geiger_counter) click. Across the entire sample, atoms decay at a rate of `λ` per second. The exponential distribution describes the distribution of how long it will be until the next click. The larger than `λ` is, the sooner that click is likely to come.

The property that you care about is that the odds that `stats_rand_gen_exponential(x)` gives a smaller number than `stats_rand_gen_exponential(y)` is `x/(x+y)`. And this scales up. So for each element, record `stats_rand_gen_exponential($element->weight)`. Sort them them ascending according to those random numbers. And the random distribution that you get is exactly what you want. Random with each element's odds of coming first exactly proportional to its weight. And so on down the line.

As for code to do that, we'll just borrow the [Schwartzian transform](https://gregheo.com/blog/schwartzian-transform/). Here is untested code for that.

```
<?php

// kludge. this function is part of the PECL stats module
if( ! function_exists('stats_rand_gen_exponential') ) {
    function stats_rand_gen_exponential(float $av) {
        return 0.5;
    }
}

class Node {
    public function __construct(public $weight) {}
}

$array = [
    new Node(10),
    new Node(20)
];

// decorate
// array_walk($array, create_function('&$v, $k', '$v = array($v, stats_rand_gen_exponential($v->weight));'));
// $array = array_map(function($v){return [$v, stats_rand_gen_exponential($v->weight)];}, $array);
$array = array_map(fn($v) => [$v, stats_rand_gen_exponential($v->weight)], $array);

// sort
// usort($array, create_function('$a,$b', 'return $a[1] <=> $b[1];'));
// usort($array, function($a, $b){return $a[1] <=> $b[1];});
usort($array, fn($a, $b) => $a[1] <=> $b[1]);

// undecorate
// array_walk($array, create_function('&$v, $k', '$v = $v[0];'));
// $array = array_map(function($v){return $v[0];}, $array);
$array = array_column($array, 0);

var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Been awhile since you last wrote a bit of PHP, eh? [`create_function()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function) was removed in 8.0, you'd want to use [anonymous functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) instead.

Comment: I believe that [this](https://3v4l.org/lX4tf) translates the posted code into anon function calls. I've also changed `array_walk()` to `array_map()` to avoid references and necessarily modifying the original array.

Comment: @Sammitch I've actually never written more than a few thousand lines of PHP. I just googled for a code sample and modifying. I'll update off of your improved version. The important bit after all is the non-obvious math.

Comment: Thank you @btilly. Excellent and well-explained answer.